# Convert date to yyyy-mm-dd from c# to sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, date-conversion

I'm developing a c# program and i need to store some date in a sql server database.
In my able I have a column type date where i need to store year, month and day. So I convert the date in c# program from dd/mm/yyyy (italian format) to yyyy-mm-dd and the I insert it in the database. When I go to read the data from the table and I display it inside the textbox i see the date followed by hours:minutes:seconds. Why? In my database I only store yyyy-mm-dd (I check it in sql management studio) and in c# program i use a string type to save the date in a property of an object:

```
    public string data_fattura
    {
        get { return checkStringGet(_data_fattura); }
        set { _data_fattura = checkDataSet(value); }
    }    

    private string checkDataSet(string data)
    {
        string[] tmp = data.Split('/');

        return tmp[2] + "-" + tmp[1] + "-" + tmp[0];
    }

    private string checkStringGet(string data)
    {
        string[] tmp = data.Split('-');

        return tmp[2] + "/" + tmp[1] + "/" + tmp[0];
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't convert it to a string at all where you don't need to.

Convert *from* the string you get from the user using `DateTime.ParseExact`, and then keep it as a `DateTime`. Use that as a parameter in parameterized SQL to insert it into the database. The database won't be storing it in a text format anyway.

When you fetch it from the database, you'll *also* have a `DateTime`. (You can just cast the value from the reader - you *don't* need to go anywhere near a text representation when fetching from the database.) When you want to display that to the user, format it appropriately (using `ToString`).

Basically, keep the value as a `DateTime` (or `DateTimeOffset`, potentially) for as much of the time as possible... as early as you can when you get the text from the user (ideally, use a control which is date/time aware so you don't even need it then) and as late as you can when you present it back to the user.

As for the time appearing - it's not entirely clear *where* it was appearing. If you only want a date, you should have a [`date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) column rather than [`datetime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx). You'll still fetch the value back as a `DateTime` .NET value, but when you convert that to a string, just use a format which is date-only. .NET doesn't have a type which is "just a date" (unfortunately, IMO).

Comment: Ok thanks now i try. Using datetime in c# will I get also time?

Comment: @pindol: Well that's part of the .NET type, but if your database type is date-only, then it's not going to start storing a time in that... If your database type is [`datetime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) then perhaps you meant [`date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) instead?

Comment: Ok. For the conversion from dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd I don't have to worry about it? Or it take the format as mm/dd/yyyy? Is there a way to set the format in which I have to convert the date?

Comment: @pindol: *What* conversion? As I said, the database isn't storing a text representation (assuming you've got a sensible column type) - it's just storing a value. So when you provide it with a `DateTime` value, there's no *concept* of converting it to any particular text representation.

Comment: when i take date value from database and assign it to my object property I get an error that say the string is not a valid datetime, here is what i write: fattura.data_fattura = DateTime.ParseExact(reader["data_fattura"].ToString(), "DD/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: @pindol: Why are you using `DateTime.ParseExact`? Just cast the value to `DateTime`: `DateTime value = (DateTime) reader["data_fattura"];` or use `reader.GetDateTime(columnNumber)`

Comment: ah ok, in your answer you wrote to use parseexact

Comment: Ok it works. So in the database the value is saved yyyy-mm-dd and then using datetime the system automatically convert it in the right format based on the one of the computer where the program is running?

Comment: @pindol: *No*. In the database, the value is just saved as a value, not in any text format. (I've already said this in the answer *and* in comments, and Heinzi has said it too.) Likewise `DateTime` itself doesn't store things in a text format. When you call `ToString` it will use a default format unless you specify one, but that's a different matter.

Comment: @pindol: And as for "in your answer you wrote to use parseexact" - that was in the context of when you get the data from the user, which is naturally in the form of text. I'll clarify it further, but I thought it was already reasonably clear given the rest of the answer...

Comment: Ok, thanks. By the way now it works and i replaced the textbox with datetimepicker so i have to do less cast and conversions.

Comment: @pindol: Right - that's the ideal, when you don't need text at all :)

Answer (score 0):

> In my database I only store yyyy-mm-dd (I check it in sql management studio)

Nope. If it is a `datetime` column, it is stored in some internal format that *always* includes date and time information, even if the latter might be `00:00:00`.

If you want to convert the value from the database to a string for displaying, use the `ToString` method to convert it into a format of your choice. In your case, you might want to use one without a time component:

```
string myStringToShow = myDateTimeFromTheDatabase.ToString("d");
```

The following MSDN page explains the meaning of `d` and tells you which other date format specifiers you can use:

- [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: The column type is date not datetime, is it different?

Comment: @pindol: Yes, then it's only the date in the database. However, when reading into a C# data type, this data type will probably be `DateTime`, which, again, includes a time component.